# Google Play Install Referrer API - Can I get data about custom store listing?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have a react-native Android app published on Google Play Store.
We created a couple Custom Store Listing pages for the same.
They are in the following format :

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exampleapp&listing=customListingValue`

I am using the [react-native-play-install-referrer](https://github.com/uerceg/play-install-referrer-react-native) for react-native, which is basically a wrapper around [Google Play Install Referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library).

**Question** :

1. My understanding is that the url needs to have a `referrer` parameter in it for this API to return data. Which also means that the Custom Store Listing URL I've provided above won't really work with this API. Is my understanding correct ?
2. Is there any other way to get data regarding which Custom Store Listing was used to install the Android app ?

Comment: I am currently on the same problem? Did you manage to solve it?